# How to find the name of a second instance of a form C#

Tags: c#

For example if I have a form called frmOne and I am there and I do some things then click a button event and it goes and takes me to a second form called frmTwo. Then I am in frmTwo and I do some things then I click a button in frmTwo and this button creates a new instance of frmOne. Since now I have two forms of frmOne open what will Visual Studios call the second instance of frmOne. I need to figure this out because I need to access it in code. I have tried using frmOne as the name to reference it in code but it doesnt work on the second instance. Any ideas how I can find this name or what Visual Studios calls it? I am assuming Visual Studios does something like calling the second instance frmOne1 or something like that. Thanks in advance.

From the example above here below frmShoppingCart is my first form. I have two instances of it open. I am trying to close the second instance from the closing event of another form. I can close the first instance with the code below and I can use it to close the second instance if I knew what the name was of the second instance which I am assuming is different from frmShoppingCart. I just am assuming Visual Studios is calling the name of my second instance of frmShoppingCart something else than frmShoppingCart.

```
private void frmViewer_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    //close shopping cart form and refresh and open the shop now form
    frmShoppingCart obj = (frmShoppingCart)Application.OpenForms["frmShoppingCart"];
    obj.Close();

}
```

Comment: Nothing, there is no such thing as a "name" for objects, unless you do and manage them. You reference them using object references and passing them along with variables and parameters.

Comment: _"creates a new instance of frmOne"_ why?

Comment: Yes in visual studios if you look under properties each form has a name. A name that you can reference in code because I have referenced it to the first form, it just doesn't work for the second form because I am assuming Visual Studios gives it a different name.

Comment: @johnnyboy1899 What name and what code are you refering to?

Comment: If you want to use Form1 in Form2 or Form2 in Form1 you can create a property in form that you need or manage situation whith event ;)

Comment: No I just need the name of the second form so I can reference it in code.

Comment: I am just wanting to know how I can find the name of the second instance of frmOne described above. In this example the name of the first form is frmOne. I create a second instance of this form and the name isn't frmOne. It is something else I am trying to figure that out.

Comment: The name is property! if you create 2 form of different type, you need to call constructor to create an instance of object, why you search the name??

Comment: Why reference it by name. Your calling code created the form; can't you hold a reference to that? By name sounds indirect to me.

Comment: @Kit yep correct

Comment: I need the name because after creating the second instance of the form, I am doing some things then moving to another form. In this form I am referencing the second instance of frmOne and I am closing it from this new form.

Comment: Every open forms is kept in a collection accessible from the Application object. It is called Application.OpenForms. With a bit of Linq you could extract the form you need (_Application.OpenForms.OfType<frmOne>()_) Then it is up to you to have a way to distinguish one instance from the other.

Comment: @johnnyboy1899 probably you wrong the logic..... post your code if you want..

Comment: @TheOverrider I figured out a better way to accomplish what I was doing instead of trying to do this. Logic wasn't wrong but their was an easier and better way to do what I needed doing.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you need to reference a form indirectly by name. You could instead hold a reference directly to the form.

If you still want to reference by name, you can, but you need some other piece of data to disambiguate the form as @Steve said in the comments. To do that you could add another property to the form. Here's a small demo form

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1() => InitializeComponent();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var f = new Form1 { Instance = ++Counter };
        f.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var forms = Application.OpenForms;
    }

    public int Instance { get; set; }

    public static int Counter { get; set; }
}
```

that shows, under the debugger with a breakpoint after

```
var forms = Application.OpenForms;
```

that you can see the disambiguation.

[image: Debugger Watch Window Screenshot 1]

Note that searching by name alone will return the first form with that name. To get the correct one, do a search using linq against [Application.OpenForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?view=net-5.0) (again, credit @Steve):

```
var myForm = Application.OpenForms
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Form1" && x.Instance == 1);
```

This is but one way to find the form. You could instead change `Name` when you create the form. Here's an example using the `Counter` above.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var f = new Form1();
    f.Name += ++Counter;
    f.ShowDialog();
}
```

This gives us

[image: Debugger Watch Window Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Singleton to have a list of named Forms opened from the first ...

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form {
      public FormsOpened Forms => FormsOpened.Instance;
      public Form1() {
         this.InitializeComponent();
      }
      protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
         base.OnLoad(e);
         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var f = default(Form);
            // Form2 is a simple empty form
            this.Forms.formsOpened.Add(f = new Form2() { Name = "Pippo" + i });
            f.Show();
         }
      }
      protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e) {
         base.OnClosing(e);
         foreach (var f in this.Forms.formsOpened) {
            f.Close();
         }
      }
   }

   public sealed class FormsOpened {
      private static FormsOpened instance = null;
      public List<Form> formsOpened = new List<Form>();
      private int counter = 0;
      public static FormsOpened Instance {
         get {
            if (instance == null) {
               instance = new FormsOpened();
            }
            return instance;
         }
      }
      private FormsOpened() {
         this.counter++;

      }
   }
```

In this way in every class you want you can access the FormsOpened Forms => FormsOpened.Instance and use it ;)